# Should I give my SSN to recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, united-states, background-check, security, applications

I got call from recruiter and he said I should give him my SSN in order to apply to job.

From his email:

> As part of our disclosures and to present you as a qualified Candidate
>   to [Company Name], your full Social Security number will be supplied
>   to [Company Name]. This is a
>   requirement of [Company Name] prior to any engagement with any Candidate.

I have doubts, because I was never asked it before when applying.

Is it normal?

Comment: I was about to post an answer to this question :/ .. I posted it on the target dupe [instead](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/114166/73791) so it can be of use still :)